# Add additional markers to existing featuregroup in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, array

It is possible to add additional markers to an existing featuregroup after it has already been added to the map?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

```
featuregroup.addLayer(marker);
```